# Firebase connection not working (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to start a project with Firebase as my Back-End and connecting it to a Android Studio project. I created around 30 projects and using the guide in Tools>Firebase on the Android Studio client, it does not connect in any way.

I've tried giving internet permissions, using other databases like FireStoreDatabase instead of the Realtime Database , sending only a "Hello world" text and a simple User (name and height) but all of them seems to work.

When I use the listeners, the simply don't give me any error. It just skip this whole step of writing data.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    System.out.println("-----------");
    myRef.setValue("Hello World").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
            System.out.println("WRITING DATA");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NOT WRITING DATA");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("-----------");
}
```

I'm also using all the dependencies that the client-assistant and the Firebase dependencies needs.
And the google-services.json file is also checked

This is the output:

> Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
> W/.firebasepresto: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
> W/.firebasepresto: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
> D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10160; state: ENABLED
> W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.firebasepresto/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dm': No such file or directory
> W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~UEPoBOUjRRSFIS2ZrGSd6w==/com.example.firebasepresto-CKvpL_AgSxGH5wAa2Mm8FQ==/base.dm': No such file or directory
> W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~UEPoBOUjRRSFIS2ZrGSd6w==/com.example.firebasepresto-CKvpL_AgSxGH5wAa2Mm8FQ==/base.dm': No such file or directory
> D/nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~UEPoBOUjRRSFIS2ZrGSd6w==/com.example.firebasepresto-CKvpL_AgSxGH5wAa2Mm8FQ==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~UEPoBOUjRRSFIS2ZrGSd6w==/com.example.firebasepresto-CKvpL_AgSxGH5wAa2Mm8FQ==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.firebasepresto
> V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.firebasepresto' set to: 'default'
> V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.firebasepresto: false
> V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
> D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
> D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
> D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10160; state: ENABLED
> I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
> D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
> D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
> W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000b/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
> W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000b/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
> D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
> I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:88 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:88
> I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
> V/FA: onActivityCreated
> W/.firebasepresto: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
> W/.firebasepresto: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
> D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10160; state: ENABLED
> V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
> V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.example.firebasepresto, 1:325373313014:android:dbb374537f8f82e24f11d7
> I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 76003
> I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
> I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
> adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.firebasepresto
> D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
> I/System.out: -----------
> I/System.out: -----------
> D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
> D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x76befcc19990, tid 17826
> D/FA: Resetting session stitching token to not null
> D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
> D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x76befcc19a50: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
> D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(78) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
> D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x76befcc19a50: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x76c12462e080) (first time)
> V/FA: Connecting to remote service
> V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
> V/FA: Session started, time: 4685124
> I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
> D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
> D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x76befcc18550, tid 17826
> D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
> D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
> I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
> W/Gralloc4: allocator 4.x is not supported
> D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
> W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
> V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 4684802
> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
> V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
> D/FA: Connected to remote service
> V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 7
> V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output you get from the `System.out.println` calls.

Comment: Have you tried to log the messages using `Log.d("YourTAG", "WRITING DATA");` instead of using `System.out.println("WRITING DATA");`? Besides that, what is the location of your database?